# Is it recommended to drink water during meals?

Tags: water, time-of-day, meal

I have heard people say that it's not recommended to drink water in between meals. Ideally, water should be consumed about 1/2 hour before or 1/2 hour after meals.

Is this true? Should we consume water during meals?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is drinking water during or after a meal better?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/is-drinking-water-during-or-after-a-meal-better)

Answer (score 2):

Drinking water during or after a meal actually aids digestion. Water and other liquids help break down food so that your body can absorb the nutrients. Water also softens stools, which helps prevent constipation.

Despite the fact that it aids digestion, it also has its down-side such as the fact that it would slow the digestion process and reduce the body’s ability to produce enough digestive enzymes to digest foods properly. Without proper digestion, a build up of toxic waste can occur no matter what you are eating.

It is important to note that drinking water during a meal would be more beneficial than not drinking while eating if you are not properly hydrated before hand. Eating while dehydrated can cause the body to have a very tough time digesting food.

Based on the information presented, when thinking about how to approach eating meals yourself, there are several tips we can apply. It appears most beneficial to stay hydrated throughout the day and if you must drink while you eat, avoid drinking too much, as well as alcohol and acidic drinks. Drink warm water and drink it sparingly. A small glass will likely not interfere with digestion and by adding a dash of apple cider vinegar or lemon, you can aid in the digestive process further. If you can, you might want to try drinking 30 minutes before and 30 minutes after a meal with no drinking during, see how you feel. If it works for you, then stick with what works, if not, adjust accordingly.

http://www.collective-evolution.com/2013/07/02/is-drinking-water-while-eating-good-for-you/

Comment: please,post your answer here too:  https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/is-drinking-water-during-or-after-a-meal-better